# Get Folder names containing .sln and .java files in SharpSVN using C#

Tags: c#, list, ankhsvn, sharpsvn

I want to search for .sln and .java files from a given remote URL: something like http://olfandsub1.olf.com/nyts/.

I tried the code below used to read all files but it isn't working. Could you please explain what the `GetList` function does in the code?

Also can you tell me if I could take a textbox value as the projectPath in the code?

What is the best way I could solve my problem?

```
    bool gotList; 
    List<string> files = new List<string>(); 

    using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient()) 
    { 
        Collection<SvnListEventArgs> list; 

        gotList = client.GetList(projectPath, out list); 

        if (gotList) 
        { 
            foreach (SvnListEventArgs item in list) 
            { 
                files.Add(item.Path); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

I also get the `"PROPFIND of '/nyts': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://olfandsub1.olf.com <http://olfandsub1.olf.com/> )"` 
 error even though my username and password are absolutely right.

Please let me know asap as I've been trying to implement this for 3 days now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like

```
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredentials("user", "password");
```

Or more cleaner hook the events on the Authentication class and provide credentials only when needed.

(The SharpSvn.UI assembly contains the default UI you see in AnkhSVN)